# Is multiple required parameters support in Angular2 router

Tags: angular, angular2-router3

Like:

```
/profiles/:category/:profileSlug/:page
```

Because I cannot generate URL with `[routerLink]="['/profiles', {category: 'president', profileSlug: 'obama', page: 1}]"` returns unexpected result in matrix query format

So in Router3 I must hard the whole URL by myself? If true then Angular's router is really...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't name the parameters in your `routerLink` attribute, just pass in the values:

```
[routerLink]="['/profiles', 'president', 'obama', 1]"
```

For `/profiles/:id/edit`:

```
[routerLink]="['/profiles', id, 'edit']"
```

Comment: Not very happy with Router 3. Thanks for you help btw.

Answer (score 0):

```
[routerLink]="[/profiles", {queryParams: {category:'president', profileSlug:'obama',page:1}}]"
```

I think this is the correct way to implement multiple required parameters

Comment: Queryparameters are something different. They are the part after `?` (or `;`) in the URL. The route parameters used in the question are part of the path of the URL.